# Tags of the week! May 6-May 12, 2019: Science Fiction & Resources — RESULTS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

## WEEK: May 6-12, 2019
TAGS: [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources)

At the start of this week [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) had 165 questions and [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) had 158. Let see how high we can get them by week's end.

At the end of the week, [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) had 176 questions and [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) had 191.

---

## Results

This was a terrific week with 6 questions from 3 users.

Congrats to our winner of the week, wetcircuit for a 2 questions on [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and 1 on [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources).  Our runner-up was Liquid, with a question on each tag.  And thanks to April for rounding out the week with a question on [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources)

Retagging efforts were also great this week and we're close to one more tag over the 200 question threshold.

---

As a followup to our [fantastic tag contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/announcing-our-contest-results?cb=1), and to suggestions that we [continue the fun](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/suggestion-continue-question-pushes/1955) in a more informal way, here is Writing.SE's sixth:

## TAGS OF THE WEEK PROMO

### Rules:

- The contest runs for one week, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or both of the tags of the week.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the week, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use both tags in the same question.

---

**Notes:**

- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this week's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal is to increase questions on tags that have not yet reached the magic 200 questions.  My personal focus is tags that are in the top 40 tags but under 200 questions.
- Others may take over other weeks and they may have different goals.
- Each week we'll have two tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

This contest is linked from [this Meta.SE post about topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327017/162102).  (Please update it for new challenges.)

For a list of all targeted tags and their progress, see https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1987/32946

Comment: That resources tag is painfully close to the 200 mark. Good job everyone

Answer (score 4):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

- Liquid: [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) [The unknown and unexplained in science fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44978/the-unknown-in-science-fiction)
- Liquid [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) [What are some good historical sources fro writing medieval battles?c](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45144/what-are-some-good-historical-sources-fro-writing-medieval-battles)
- April: [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) ["[x] minutes to read?" How do they calculate that?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44981/x-minutes-to-read-how-do-they-calculate-that)
- wetcircuit: [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)
  [Can I bring back Planetary Romance as a genre?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45023/can-i-bring-back-planetary-romance-as-a-genre)
- wetcircuit [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)
  [Is every story set in the future "science fiction"?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45062/is-every-story-set-in-the-future-science-fiction)
- wetcircuit [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources)
  [Many sexual situations, but no actual sex scenes?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45083/many-sexual-situations-but-no-actual-sex-scenes)